# rsync with launchd on OS X always gives me error code 255

Tags: macos, rsync, launchd

I want to rsync my `/var/repo` backup to a remote machine when it changes.
I made a ssh key pairs to make my machine can ssh login to remote without password(ignore details).

I added a file `com.ph.rsync2.plist` in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`.
The content is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ph.rsync2.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
   <string>/usr/bin/rsync</string>
   <string>-avz</string>
   <string>--rsh=ssh</string>
   <string>/var/repo</string>
   <string>flora@192.168.19.28:/var/ph_backups/</string>
    </array>

    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/var/repo</string>
    </array>

</dict>
```

Then I `launchctl load com.ph.rysnc2.plist`. 
When `/var/repo` has any change, it will trigger rsync to work 
but I always get the error log in Console.app
It reads like

```
11/3/15 2:15:26.399 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: 
(com.ph.rsync2.plist) Service only ran for 1 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 9 seconds.
```

And I tried to move the rsync commands to a script, then let launchd exec my script. but it's still the same

I can't figure out which part of settings make all these fail.

Anyone can give me a clue?

Comment: It may be easier to put the rsync command in a bash script, check that works when you call it directly, then get launchd to call your script.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I've tried your way. no luck

Comment: Dose the script run correctly outside of launchd?

Comment: Yes. since launchd doesn't work for me, I have to run my script in terminal

Comment: Configure `StandardErrorPath` to see what rsync complains about.

Comment: @LCC Hͧoͧw can I set `StandardErrorPath` ?

Answer (score 1):

Comments will mess up the formatting, so I'll post how to setup the `StandardErrorPath` key as an answer.

Modify your job definition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.ph.rsync2.plist</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/rsync</string>
        <string>-avz</string>
        <string>--rsh=ssh</string>
        <string>/var/repo</string>
        <string>flora@192.168.19.28:/var/ph_backups/</string>
    </array>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/tmp/com.ph.rsync2.plist.stderr</string>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/var/repo</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Check the file `/tmp/com.ph.rsync2.plist.stderr` after reloading and starting the job.

Comment: I added a `StandardErrorPath `. there's nothing in `/tmp/com.ph.rsync2.plist.stderr`. maybe the launchd can't run rsync or ssh correctly. Is there any other way I can try?

Comment: But the file exists, right? No more output in the system log, just the line you've posted? Which version of OSX are you using? If you're on 10.10+ please provide the relevant section of the output of the command: `launchctl dumpstate`. Relevant is everything between `com.ph.rsync2.plist = {` and the next line beginning with `}`. Also a line looking similar to `?     ?     com.ph.rsync2.plist` is of interest.

Comment: Yes, the file exists but it